# Правильно ли поставлены двоеточия?

Tags: пунктуация

Из того же текста. Меня смутило, что два двоеточия подряд. Правильно они поставлены тут или нет: "На следущее утро анализы крови изменились в лучшую сторону: можно было лететь в Томск. Что это было: совпадение или вмешательство Божественных сил?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом предложении вторая часть означает следствие того, о чем говорится в первой части сложного предложения. В таком случае однозначно ставится тире.

Answer (score 1):

Двоеточия находятся в разных предложениях. Количество двоеточий в тексте ничем не ограничивается. Но, может быть, в первом предложении лучше поставить тире? Ведь первая часть содержит причину того, о чем говорится во второй.

Answer (score 0):

Количество двоеточий в тексте обычно никому не мешает, бросается в глаза обилие некоторых других знаков (тире, кавычек и проч.), но двоеточие само по себе к таковым не относится.

Конкретно по фразе.
В первом случае я бы поставил запятую, двоеточие знась весьма "авторский" знак, подчеркивающий, что во второй части содержится только вывод из первой, но это и так ясно по контексту, дополнительное акцентирование тут не нужно. 
Во втором случае двоеточие можно оставить, хотя сейчас именно в подобных случаях двоеточие часто заменяют на тире.

Меня еще немного смушает "анализы изменились" да еще в "лучшую сторону". Какой-то очень "деревянный" язык. Дал бы вариант, но даже саму ситуацию плохо представляю.

Comment: Это цитата из письма в редакцию — писал не журналист, поэтому и слог такой.

Comment: Тогда сохраняйте "орфографию автора". Я вообще считаю, что в таких случаях править набо только тогдла, когда не править нельзя.

Comment: причём тут орфография?